# how to pass richtext generated html content from jsp to js file

Tags: aem, richtext

I have a richtext component, I gave input as "foo" to richtext component, and it generated
`<p>foo</p>`, I'm trying to pass this generated content from JSP to JS using the following code.

```
    <script>
    var jsvariable = '<%=jspvariable%>'
    </script>
```

the above line throws "unterminated string literal" error, as the JS variable contains

```
    ptagstarts foo ptagends
```

I'm using the value in JS as I need this variable in other pages as well.
May I know how we to remove this error.

Comment: Can you post there declaration of *jspvariable*?

Comment: I would try to escape the String first, e.g. with https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: @Alex, it is a String variable

Comment: I see, but as you can see, you have some extra content there, to understand what is wrong, it would be nice to see how you extract this String value from you component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, seems, that you have in your **jspvariable** string `</script>`. Html parser treats it as ending of the **script** block, and you getting invalid **script** block.

You can check source of your page to be sure, that I am right.

As Thomas suggested, you can escape your content. But as long as this content is provided by user, I would use XssApi, to prevent xss attack as well.

So it would be something like:

```
var jsvariable = '<%=xssApi.encodeForJSString(jspvariable)%>'
```

Or:

```
var jsvariable = '<%=xssApi.filterHTML(jspvariable)%>'
```

In first case you will get that `<script>` block from richtext component into your js variable. It will be encoded, and you will not get this error, but I think you do not need it.

In second case, you, should get only text value from you component.

**UPDATE 1**

Also, as I wrote you in comments, It would be nice to see the way you extract content from your richtext component, because I think, there is a better way of doing this, so you will get only text without anything else.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your answer, I need the html tags to be retained, as I need them styling the rendered content.For now I will try your suggestion for using xssApi and update you, thanks again :)

Comment: Hi, I have used encodeForJSString method, and it worked, thanks Alex.